# Apache Pig Error Messages Guide

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I'm looking for resources on how to interpret various common PIG scripting error messages. Something of a first stop before venturing to Google/SO.

Ideally I'd like a single page or searchable authoritative reference listing:

- Common error messages
- Likely causes
- Typical solutions

Know of any good references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pig's [Error handling func spec](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/PIG/PigErrorHandlingFunctionalSpecification) contains a detailed information about error types/codes.
Since this hasn't been updated in the recent past I'd also suggest you to have a
look the source code if something is unclear happens.

Comment: So I'm looking for something that translates between the "Compendium of Errors" and English...

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't any such guide available. This is the far most
detailed one I've seen so far.